# Text is not rotating with button

Tags: html, css

I need help rotating text at the same time that the button rotates. For some reason the text is currently disappearing when I hover the mouse over the button. The text should not be disappearing; it should be rotating with the button I'm using Chrome for this project.

http://codepen.io/matosmtz/pen/oXBaQE

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class = "container">
    <section class="3d-button">
      <h2>Animated Button</h2>
      <p class="btn_perspective">
        <button class="btn btn-3d btn-3da">Submit</button>
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Lekton;
    background: rgb(245,245,245);
}

a {
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.container > section {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 6em 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.btn {
    border:none;
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(245,245,245);
    padding: 15px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    color: inherit;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: .9em;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.btn_perspective {
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.btn-3d {
    display: block;
    background: #5cbcf6;
    color: white;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.btn-3d:active {
    background: #55b7f3;
}

.btn-3da:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 42%;
    left: 0;
    top: -40%;
    background: #53a6d7;
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

.btn-3da:hover {
    transform: rotateX(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: your codepen is not working

Comment: That's strange! I just double checked it and it's working fine. The button should rotate on hover and return to its original state on hover out.

Comment: The code is customized to only work on Google Chrome by the way.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like this (works in all major web browsers): http://infosoft.biz/ ?

Comment: Eventually I would want it to work on all browsers but I left out all the code that would make it compatible with other browsers because I'm currently prototyping with Chrome. I'll add the code to make it work with Mozilla right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpaGYd

Added the following code to your button:

```
.btn-3da:after {
 z-index:1;
}

.btn-3da:hover {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into this pure CSS3 solution (works in all major web browsers: [**DEMO**](http://infosoft.biz/)):

```
/*ROTATE*/
.divRotate 
{
    -moz-transition     : all 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition  : all 0.8s;
    -o-transition       : all 0.8s;
    transition          : all 0.8s;
}
.divRotate:hover 
{

    -moz-transform      : rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform   : rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform        : rotate(360deg);
    transform           : rotate(360deg);
}
```

Add the div element to your HTML and refer the `class = 'divRotate'`.

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: Hi Alex, your solution rotates the image in a 2D space; however, I am trying to rotate the image in a 3D space.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Just in case, you have an alternative version. Best regards,